# How can I set default focus in datapicker is to day and value in input is empty

Tags: html, datepicker

I'm using datapicker to set date start and end input. I want to show focus today in calendar when user click in input, so I use set newDate but it set date in input. I want default input is empty. Here is my code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#startdate")
            .datepicker({format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'})
            .datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        $("#enddate")
            .datepicker({format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'})
            .datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    });
```

In html

```
<div class="row input-daterange input-group" style="padding-bottom: 20px" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <label for="order_date" class="label">
                        <strong>Date Label</strong>
                    </label>

                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="start">
                            <strong>Start</strong>
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-group datepicker-container">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start" id="startdate" value="{{ old('start', request()->start ?? '') }}"/>
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="end">
                            <strong>End</strong>
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-group datepicker-container">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="end" id="enddate" value="{{ old('end', request()->end ?? '') }}"/>
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, after all i add highlightToDay to focus in today when user click.

```
 $("#startdate, #enddate")
    .datepicker({
         format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
         todayHighlight: true
     });
```